# Checking to see if the 1, 2 and 3rd element in a list is an integer Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a line that I stripped and split into strings. I checked to see if the first element in the list is indeed the string I am looking for. Now I need to check if elements 1 to 2 in the list are integers 0-9 (inclusive) This is what I have so far, but I feel like there must be a cleaner way to write this.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
   
    line = line.strip() #strips line of whitespace
    line = line.split() #splits line into strings

    if not line[0].startswith("#"): #if line does not begin with #comment, it will read in
        if line[0] == "init" and line[1].isnumeric() and line[2].isnumeric():
           
            wid = int(line[1])
            hei = int(line[2])
            init(wid, hei)

        else:
            print("Input error: Faulty init(value, value) Command ")
            sys.exit()  #terminates program
```

Comment: Take a slice and use any with a list comprehension

Comment: `if all(l.isdigit() for l in line[1:4])`?

Comment: Thank you chris, that was very helpful way to use list comprehension.  :)